# DjangoRestFramework - How can I use 'pk' to filter a list?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to filter a list of `BatchLog` objects according to `pk` that I send through the request - which is their `batch_id`. Is there a way to access it on `views.py` file?

I have this in my `urls.py` file

```
path('feed/<int:pk>', GetFeedItemView.as_view())
```

And in my views.py file I want to access a `BatchLog` object by filtering its `batch_id`

```
class GetFeedItemView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = FeedSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return BatchLog.objects.filter(batch_id=self.request.pk)
```

This `filter(batch_id=self.request.pk)` doesn't work but I want to implement it in the same logic.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ***`self.kwargs["pk"]`***

```
class GetFeedItemView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = FeedSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return BatchLog.objects.filter(batch_id=self.kwargs["pk"])
```